# How to convert string to uppercase / lowercase in Jinja2?

Tags: python, jinja2

I am trying to convert to upper case a string in a Jinja template I am working on.

In the [template documentation](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/templates/), I read:

```
upper(s)
    Convert a value to uppercase.
```

So I wrote this code:

```
{% if student.department == "Academy" %}
    Academy
{% elif  upper(student.department) != "MATHS DEPARTMENT" %}
    Maths department
{% endif %}
```

But I am getting this error:

```
UndefinedError: 'upper' is undefined
```

So, how do you convert a string to uppercase in Jinja2?

Comment: For Google, the error for lowercase is: `jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'lower' is undefined`

Answer (score 146, accepted):

Filters are used with the [`|filter` syntax](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/templates/#filters):

```
{% elif  student.department|upper != "MATHS DEPARTMENT" %}
    Maths department
{% endif %}
```

or you can use the [`str.upper()` method](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.upper):

```
{% elif  student.department.upper() != "MATHS DEPARTMENT" %}
    Maths department
{% endif %}
```

Jinja syntax is Python-*like*, not actual Python.

Comment: similarly, `student.department.lower() != "maths department"` does the lowercase

Answer (score 50):

**for the capitalize**

```
{{ 'helLo WOrlD'|capitalize }}
```

*output*

```
Hello world
```

**for the uppercase**

```
{{ 'helLo WOrlD'|upper }}
```

*output*

```
HELLO WORLD
```

Comment: I am using `capfirst` as `capitalize` thows the error: invalid filter.

Answer (score 40):

For **Capitalize** (for 3.1+ versions of Jinja2)

```
{{ 'helLo WOrlD'|capitalize }}
```

<s>For **Capitalize**</s>

```
{{ 'helLo WOrlD'|capfirst }}
```

(outdated, for old versions of Jinja2)

For **UPPER CASE**

```
{{ 'helLo WOrlD'|upper }}
```

For **lower case**

```
{{ 'helLo WOrlD'|lower }}
```

For **title**

```
{{ 'helLo WOrlD'|title }}
```

For **ljust**

```
{{ 'helLo WOrlD'|ljust }}
```

For **rjust**

```
{{ 'helLo WOrlD'|rjust }}
```

For **wrap**

```
{{ 'helLo WOrlD'|wrap }}
```

Hope It Helps

Comment: For capitalize, it is `capitalize` and not `capFirst` for me, on Jinja2.

Comment: @NoelBautista You are using different version of jinja2. Probably you are using the latest version, Please check

Comment: yes, I am on `Jinja2==3.1.2`. Perhaps add the major version your answer is for.

Answer (score 4):

And you can use: Filter like this

```
{% filter upper %}
    UPPERCASE
{% endfilter %}
```

Comment: But this won't let you compare the result; only *interpolates* the result.